# The site of "Welcome to nginx!" not appearing as I `curl http://your_server_ip`

Tags: nginx

I've been doing [the tutorial](https://tutpoints.xyz/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-20-04/) of nginx.

The below image is from the tutorial.

[image]

And as I `curl http://my_ip` ,

```sh
curl: (28) Failed to connect to my_ip port 80 after 130496 ms: Connection timed out
```

is returned after long wait.

What cause(s) can be thought?

BTW the following commands work well.

```sh
curl http://127.0.0.1
curl http://localhost
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least for my configurations, just rebooting my computer has worked for me.

Comment: Many times instead of IP use localhost for testing in a faster way

Comment: Got it! So you mean that curl httP://my_ip not working is not a critical problem? BTW I've failed again to gain a response from ip.

Comment: Actually to understand that you will need to have understanding of networking topics like public ip address and private ip address. And the example given in tutorial is for server other then your local system  which is accessible by public IP address. For local system curl may not be good approach to access as well as when you request internet to make you reach at your IP address it gets you into trouble. So for local system you can use 127.0.0.1 or localhost instead of your public IP address.